Forwarding property value to MarkupExtension-argument of a converter
I need 10 radio buttons with different background colors.
So I created an Enum containing 10 items:
public enum UIFunctions
{
Remarks=0
...
}

Next I created a converter transferring my UIFunctions into background color:
public class UIItemToBackgroundColorConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
  public UIFunctions Function {get; set;}
  
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, Cultureinfo culture)
  {
    if (value == null) return Binding.DoNothing;

    //call function of my ViewModel-object to read the color from DB
    return (value as MyAppViewModel).UIItem_Backgroundcolor(Function); 
  }

  ...ConvertBack ...
  ...ProvideValue...
}

Defined a property UIItem_Info_Remarks
public bool UIItem_Info_Remarks
{
  get {...}
  set {...NotifyPropertyChanged...}
}

And finally defined a RibbonRadioButton with background color in my xaml file:
<StackPanel Background="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                         Converter={converters:UIItemToBackgroundColorConverter
                         Function={x:Static local:UIFunctions.Remarks}}}">
  <RibbonRadioButton Label="Remarks" IsChecked="{Binding UIItem_Info_Remarks, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>

In this constellation it worked fine, but I needed 10 of them!
So I created a user control having this.DataContext = this; in the code behind for properties to be found. Also, I created a property UIItemCaption in the user control to pass caption and a dependency property UIItem_Value to pass value. I moved xaml-Part into a user control and I had to change RelativeSource Self to RelativeSource TemplatedParent because the converter wasn't found.
Now the problem: How can I pass in the "user control"-xaml the UIFunction needed by converter?
<StackPanel Background="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                         Converter={converters:UIItemToBackgroundColorConverter
                         Function={????}}}">
  <RibbonRadioButton Label="{Binding UIItemCaption}" IsChecked="{Binding UIItem_Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>

... and in the app-xaml file:
<local:RadioButtonWithBackColor UIItemCaption="Remark" UIItem_Value="..." Function=????>
</local:RadioButtonWithBackColor>


Why the Function property in the UIItemToBackgroundColorConverter class instead of making use of the Binding's ConverterParameter?

As a note, you should not be using the as operator without checking the result for a possible null value. The expression (value as MyAppViewModel).UIItem_Backgroundcolor(Function) would throw a NullReferenceException in case value is not a MyAppViewModel. It would be more appropriate to get an InvalidCastException, by writing ((MyAppViewModel)value).UIItem_Backgroundcolor(Function). Or just check if the result is null.

@Clemens
I liked the idea of type safety in this approach. Also it increases readability of the code. But usage of ConverterParameter would be technically possible, yes.

@Clemens In my code I have a try/catch-block around this function call. I omitted it trying give a complete image of my state but not to overload the question, which is really a long-read. Any ideas concerning actual question?

@moderator: This question is not a duplicate of the proposed one. In the proposed question converter parameter is a fixed value in the chain [App] -> [Converter]. I need means to forward a specific value through user control to converter. In my case the chain is [App] -> [user control] -> [converter]. And this "forwarding" is what I cannot figure out. Please reopen my question.
